# Ler vários objetos em arquivo serializável Java

Tags: java, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Eu tenho um arquivo `Produtos.ser` onde foram gravados vários objetos do tipo `Objeto`.
No método do código abaixo, eu desejo recuperar todos os objetos do arquivo e armazenar numa lista ArrayList.

Porém, ele adiciona no ArrayList apenas o primeiro objeto. Alguma ajuda?

```java
public ArrayList<Produto> recuperarProdutos(){
    ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    Produto p = new Produto();

    ObjectInputStream leitorObj = null;
    FileInputStream leitorArquivo = null;
    try {
        leitorArquivo = new FileInputStream("files\\Produtos.ser");
        leitorObj = new ObjectInputStream(leitorArquivo);
        p = (Produto)leitorObj.readObject();
        produtos.add(p);
    } catch(EOFException e) {
    try {
        leitorArquivo.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (leitorArquivo != null) leitorArquivo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return produtos;
}
```

Comment: Existe apenas um item na lista `produtos` porque dá apenas um `add` nela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente ler da seguinte forma:

```
while(true){
   try{
     p = (Produto)leitorObj.readObject();
     produtos.add(p);
   catch(Exception e){
     break;
   }
}
return produtos;
```

Imagino que isso deva solucionar o seu problema. Estou me baseando [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849449/how-to-prevent-inputstream-readobject-from-throwing-eofexception). Isso é quando você não sabe quantos objetos tem, o que eu aconselho fazer é salvar o número de registros e substituir o `while(true)` por `for(int i = 0; i < numObjetos; i++)`, aí o `try\catch` passa a ser desnecessário.

Comment: O java não reconheceu essa classe EndOfStremSignal nem deu sugestão de Import, tentei substituir por null, tbm nao deu certo

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta, pra te atender.

Comment: Seria bom você armazenar o error em um arquivo de log, ou verificar o estado do buffer para ver se existe algo disponível antes de tentar ler da stream, ou pelo menos usar catch(IOException) ao invés de catch(Exception).